# Backing Plate Chrysler 200 2012

Tags: chrysler, 200

There are several options of Backing Plate for the Chrysler 200 2012, as shown in the [mopar parts overstock website](https://www.moparpartsoverstock.com/productSearch.aspx?ukey_make=1094&modelYear=2012&ukey_model=15905&ukey_trimLevel=20135&ukey_driveline=13202&ukey_Category=0&numResults=50&sortOrder=Relevance&ukey_tag=0&isOnSale=0&isAccessory=0&isPerformance=0&searchTerm=Backing%20Plate).

| Rear Left | Price | Rear Right | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 05191219AB | $43.12 | 05191220AB | $41.10 |
| 68001747AD | $66.64 | 68001746AD | $68.66 |
| 68159653AA | $120.51 | 68159652AA | $45.42 |
| 68159685AA | $45.12 | 68159684AA | $63.31 |

- Why so many different parts?
- What is their difference?
- Can I pick just the cheapest one?
- Why would someone pick a more expensive one?

---

INFO on my car according to my Vehicle Documents

- YEAR: 12
- CYL: 04
- MODEL: 2LX
- POWER CARBURANT: G

Comment: Which engine does the car have, the I4 or V6?

Comment: Part of the deal is, you need to know the manufacture date of your car. The breaking point is 4 Dec 2011. At that date and after is one type. Before that date is another.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2, 2.4L

Comment: I just called the store to ask. They say that, according to the last eight digits of my vin number `CN170881`, I should be getting the parts `68159653AA` and `68159652AA`. The guy there are some small differences from vehicle to vehicle that you can only tell based on the VIN number. He didn't know what is the difference, but it could not fit if buying a different one.

Comment: The problem is, everywhere I go, they say these parts are on backorder. I need to get my car safetied ASAP and I can't wait forever for these parts. I wish there is a place that I could go online and check how the other parts are different. I am just changing the rotors, callipers and breaks and they didn't seem to be that vehicle specific (VIN) when I bought the new parts.

Comment: Some places don’t check, they expect you to know what are asking for.

Comment: @EduardoReis - The reason he used the VIN was to get when it was manufactured. They'll have the cutoff date/time by VIN, which is sequential. That's at least part of the equation. As you have listed in the answer you posted, the other part of it is the rotor diameter. No idea ***what*** they changed before/after the date ... just know ***something*** changed which makes them incompatible.

Answer (score 1):

From the description on [this seller](https://www.moparonline.ca/), these parts differ at least on rotor diameter.

| Rear Left | Price | Rear Right | Price | Rotor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [05191219AB](https://www.moparonline.ca/oem-parts/mopar-splash-shield-5191219ab) | $56.43 CAD | [05191220AB](https://www.moparonline.ca/oem-parts/mopar-splash-shield-5191220ab) | $53.18 CAD | 262mm |
| [68001747AD](https://www.moparonline.ca/oem-parts/mopar-backing-plate-68001747ad) | $84.67 CAD | [68001746AD](https://www.moparonline.ca/oem-parts/mopar-backing-plate-68001746ad) | $87.25 CAD | 302mm |
| [68159653AA](https://www.moparonline.ca/oem-parts/mopar-backing-plate-68159653AA) | $155.74 CAD | [68159652AA](https://www.moparonline.ca/oem-parts/mopar-backing-plate-68159652AA) | $57.23 CAD | 262mm |
| [68159685AA](https://www.moparonline.ca/oem-parts/mopar-backing-plate-68159685AA) | $56.85 CAD | [68159684AA](https://www.moparonline.ca/oem-parts/mopar-backing-plate-68159684aa) | $80.44 CAD | 302mm |

This [order seller](https://www.rockauto.com/) puts these parts as being equivalent.

| Rear Left | Rear Right | Rotor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 68159685AA {#68001747AD} | 68159684AA {#68001746AD} | 302mm |